# Remote service call from webclient Java : Spring Webflux

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-webclient

I have a requirement where I have a 500+ ids in a request and I have to call a remote service .
But the problem is remote service is not performant so it gets timed out . So at max I can send only 100 ids in a request. Is there a way Spring WebFlux so that I can send 500+ requests in a batch manner and at whole I can get a response .
TIA

Sample request :

{"ids": "1","2","3",.....,
"510","511"
}

Thought of using Flux.merge() but not sure .

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add a brief description, code, errors of your search/research efforts as is suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I have made it working by sending requests in batch .